# How can I add a view to the front page news feed?

Tags: views, feeds

I have created a view and I would like to promote the link to this view on the front page. How can I do this?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I would like the view to show up in the front page news feed like in line along with other content that is "promoted to front page"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a View block and display this block in any region like other blocks. Then make this block to show only listed pages, which is `<front>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but please see **UPDATE 1** above. Thanks

Comment: You may wanna add the "Term reference" field on that content type. That is based on Taxonomy term. I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [empty front page](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_front_page) to remove the promoted to the front page behavior. After that can created a block view and display it on the front page.

Another option would be to created a page view and setup this page to be in the front page at this page 
`admin/config/system/site-information`